# Why I can't update my SQL Server table using this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Currently, I been doing a programming for a website using asp.net that extract and update data from Microsoft SQL Server.

Right now I need to update certain value in certain column in certain table, but my update `SqlCommand` is not working. I already do some researched around the internet but it is not working. There are no error, but the value in SQL server table in column `WeightageFactor` on row Criticality didn't update when I click the button. I use this SQL query and it works just fine:

```
UPDATE dbo.HullPoF 
SET WeightageFactor = 0.10 
WHERE Criticality = 'Fatigue Loading'
```

This is my code:

```
protected void btnSubmitPoF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBconn1"].ConnectionString);

    commPoF = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.HullPoF SET WeightageFactor = @WF WHERE Criticality='Fatigue Loading'", conn1);
    commPoF.Parameters.Add("@WF", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtWFFatLoad.Text; ;

    conn1.Open();
    commPoF.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn1.Close();
}
```

What is wrong with my code? One of the solution I try to use is from [Update table using SqlCommand in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851335/update-table-using-sqlcommand-in-asp-net)

The current value is 0.20 and I want to change to 0.10

p/s: This is my first question in this website. If my question format is wrong please tell me.

Comment: Do you get an error? How do you know it's not working?  Have you tried tracing the SQL with SQL Server Profiler to see if there is anything wrong with the generated SQL?

Comment: Because the value in SQL server table didn't change for the column WeightageFactor on row Criticality. I use "UPDATE dbo.HullPoF SET WeightageFactor=0.10 WHERE Criticality='Fatigue Loading'" and it work fine

Comment: Probably the issue coming from double semicolons in SQL parameter declaration here: "commPoF.Parameters.Add("@WF", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtWFFatLoad.Text; ;". Make sure the datatype matched with column datatype, and txtWFFatLoad value exists. I suggest you to use a stored procedure for updating DB values rather than writing update query directly on SqlCommand.

Comment: I highly recommend you to move this code as stored procedure instead, this way you can isolate the the problem, make sure that your SQL is working 100% and then work on the C#

Comment: What is the datatype of the `WeightageFactor` column, and what is it's current value (before attempting to update)?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto already remove the semicolon but still not working

Comment: @BrendanGreen datatype for WeightageFactor is nvarchar(10) but since I getting the data from the text which is string, i didn't need to convert. The current value is 0.10

Comment: @SufyanJabr what is stored procedure? Sorry for the noob question, I'm a self-taught

Comment: Sorry, the current value is 0.20 and I want to change into 0.10

Comment: [Here's some information on stored procedures.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx) A simple way of thinking about it is that it's a method in your SQL server that you can call into - you can pass parameters in, perform operations, and get data out. As @SufyanJabr points out, it's a good way to separate database logic from code logic.

Comment: `SET WeightageFactor = 0.10 ` is not normally how an NVARCHAR is altered in SQL Server  It would normally be `SET WeightageFactor = '0.10'`

Comment: Have you tried to use `like` instead of `=`? please check: `... WHERE Criticality like '%Fatigue Loading%'`

Comment: A silly thing to check - are you certain that you are not connecting to a different database from your app compared to whatever tool it is that you are testing the query in (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewed back through hundreds of code line in project especially in Page_Load, it seem the problem was something to do with Post Back function.

All I have to do is to put

`if(!IsPostBack) { }`

to some of my code in Page_Load

Sorry to waste everyone time with my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your problem and the syntax is correct. Check the connection string.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your quality up

Comment: Yes, my WeightageFactor in nvarchar type, nvarchar(10) to be exact. Like i state in my question "UPDATE dbo.HullPoF SET WeightageFactor=0.10 WHERE Criticality='Fatigue Loading'" is working fine in my SQL query (without the quote) where the value in column WeightageFactor on row Criticality update from 0.20 to 0.10

Comment: Let's not edit answers in order to essentially comment back to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If `WeightageFactor`  is **double** so convert it and send it to parameters

```
double WF = double.Parse( txtWFFatLoad.Text);
commPoF.Parameters.Add("@WF", SqlDbType.Float);
commPoF.Parameters["@WF"].Value = WF;
```

If `WeightageFactor`  is **string** so 
Use

```
commPoF.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WF",txtWFFatLoad.Text);
```

Comment: My WeightageFactor is in nvarchar(10), not double, so I don't need to convert the data in the txtWFFatLoad.Text.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
commPoF.Parameters.Add("@WF", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtWFFatLoad.Text;
```

with

```
commPoF.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WF", txtWFFatLoad.Text);
```

Comment: I try but still with the same problem